# Clickhouse: Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted - CentOS 7, no docker image

Tags: linux, centos7, service, systemctl

I am trying to set up a Clickhouse server on my [WSL which is based on CentOS](https://github.com/yuk7/CentWSL). After following instructions [in this page](https://packagecloud.io/Altinity/clickhouse/install#bash-rpm), and installing the DB successfully, when I want to enable the service I get following:

```
# systemctl enable clickhouse-server
clickhouse-server.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig clickhouse-server on
```

And when I want to start the service, I get the below error:

```
# systemctl start clickhouse-server
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

I googled but all I got were issues about CentOS docker images which did not work for me.
Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue trying to run "systemctl" on a CentOS 7 WSL2 distribution.

Following the steps described in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/ worked for me.

TL;DR: add a "/etc/wsl.conf" file with the contents below to your WSL distribution filesystem. After a complete shutdown of wsl with "wsl --shutdown", your VM should allow "systemctl".

[boot]
systemctl=true

Answer (score 0):

I've been googling the exact same thing.

apachectl start in Centos7 seems to work for me. Same with mariadb.

Not sure how helpful that is. I've run httpd directly. Maybe you could do the same with clickhouse?